# How to enable reachability without touching buttons at bottom of screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I activate reachability on iPhone 13 without causing buttons at the bottom of the screen to be pressed?

I have already tried the "double tap back of phone for reachability" but do not like it because it is too slow to activate after double-tapping, and often doesn't activate at all - especially with a flip case on

Comment: What is reachability?

Comment: Well, I've learned something! I didn't know iPhones did the back tap.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths be careful tapping on the back you can put the phone in a highty zoomed mode. When I get this I have to go to another computer to search for an answer here how to get out of that state. Gestures are extremely difficult to use.

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, there's a double and triple tap setting. Only set one of them for a test and actually not something I'll be using often. You might need to review what you've set yours to..

Answer (score 1):

Swipe down on  bottom of the screen is the activation gesture for Reachability.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/reachability-iph145eba8e9/ios

Comment: That causes buttons on the bottom of the screen to be pressed

Comment: A swipe is not a button press, but if that's truly an issue for you, swipe between the buttons.

Comment: the buttons can be full-width and unavoidable, in almost every chinese app this is the case (wechat, alipay)